# How to ensure correct struct-field alignment between C++ and OpenGL when passing indirect drawing commands for use by glDrawElementsIndirect?

Tags: c++, opengl, struct, memory-alignment

The documentation for glDrawElementsIndirect, glDrawArraysIndirect, glMultiDrawElementsIndirect, etc. says things like this about the structure of the commands that must be given to them:

> The parameters addressed by *indirect* are packed into a structure that takes the form (in C):
>
> ```
> typedef  struct {
>     uint  count;
>     uint  instanceCount;
>     uint  firstIndex;
>     uint  baseVertex;
>     uint  baseInstance;
> } DrawElementsIndirectCommand;
> ```

When a struct representing a vertex is uploaded to OpenGL, it's not just sent there as a block of data--there are also calls like glVertexAttribFormat() that tell OpenGL where to find attribute data within the struct.  But as far as I can tell from reading documentation and such, nothing like that happens with these indirect drawing commands.  Instead, I gather, you just write your drawing-command struct in C++, like the above, and then send it over via glBufferData or the like.

The OpenGL headers I'm using declare types such as GLuint, so I guess I can be confident that the ints in my command struct will be the right size and have the right format.  But what about the alignment of the fields and the size of the struct?  It appears that I just have to trust OpenGL to expect exactly what I happen to send--and from what I read, that could in theory vary depending on what compiler I use.  Does that mean that, technically, I just have to expect that I will get lucky and have my C++ compiler choose just the struct format that OpenGL and/or my graphics driver and/or my graphics hardware expects?  Or is there some guarantee of success here that I'm not grasping?

(Mind you, I'm not truly worried about this.  I'm using a perfectly ordinary compiler, and planning to target commonplace hardware, and so I expect that it'll probably "just work" in practice.  I'm mainly only curious about what would be considered strictly correct here.)

Answer (score 0):

It is a buffer object (`DRAW_INDIRECT_BUFFER` to be precise); it is expected to contain a contiguous array of that struct. The correct type is, as you mentioned, `GLuint`. This is always a 32-bit unsigned integer type. You may see it referred to as `uint` in the OpenGL specification or in extensions, but understand that in the C language bindings you are expected to add `GL` to any such type name.

You generally are not going to run into alignment issues on desktop platforms on this data structure since each field is a 32-bit scalar. The GPU can fetch those on any 4-byte boundary, which is what a compiler would align each of the fields in this structure to. If you threw a `ubyte` somewhere in there, then you would need to worry, but of course you would then be using the wrong data structure.

As such there is only one requirement on the GL side of things, which stipulates that the beginning of this struct has to begin on a word-aligned boundary. That means only addresses (offsets) that are multiples of **4** will work when calling `glDrawElementsIndirect (...)`. Any other address will yield `GL_INVALID_OPERATION`.

Comment: So there is not actually a guarantee of compatibility here, in the standards or whatever?

Comment: @mjwach: It guarantees compatibility insofar as `GLuint` is always 32-bit. x86 has no alignment requirements of any sort, though it performs better if a 32-bit integer is aligned on a 4-byte boundary. On a desktop platform you generally don't have to worry about the compiler aligning this structure oddly. For example, Microsoft Visual C++ defaults to 8-byte alignment - data types are placed on an 8-byte boundary or some multiple of the data type's size (4-byte in this case), whichever is smaller. That causes issues with 128-bit SSE types though, so they must be explicitly aligned to 16-bytes.

Comment: @mjwach: Long story short, since Visual C++ can place each of these on a 4-byte boundary without adding any padding, this data structure will be tightly packed and alignment is not an issue. It's not GL's responsibility to guarantee this behavior, you have to know how your compiler is configured. _Just know that GL expects the data to be tightly packed; how you accomplish that is up to you._